# Limit Postback Button for Facebook Bot To One TIme Use

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have made a postback button that appears when a user messages the Facebook page a specific phrase, with 3 options to choose from as a trivia competition:
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3

Users can click an option, they will receive a follow-up message if it's right or wrong. If user clicks the right one, another postback button with question appears to continue, however if user clicks wrong one, just text gets sent that they have lost.

However, they still have the previous postback message that if they lose, they can choose the correct option to continue.

Is there a way to implement that the postback button be overwritten with new postback button, or if already selected an option not able to choose a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Floating Buttons ( Quick Reply ) for this purpose. When any user press floating buttons, the buttons disappear. 
You can attach quick reply with your generic template card too. 
See more about Quick Replies here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/quick-replies/